# Правильно ли поставлены запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

"После того, как боль чуть-чуть отходит, я разгибаюсь и смотрю на своего обидчика"

Answer (score 1):

Можно и так. А можно составной союз и не расчленять **(После того как** боль отходит, я разгибаюсь...)- зависит от автора, от интонации, с которой произносится фраза. Я бы не расчленяла.

Comment: Я бы тоже. Вообще союзы в начале фразы (наречие не в счет) обычно не расчленяют.

Answer (score 0):

Почти во всех книгах, которые читал, авторы в начале предложения союз не расчленяли, хотя это вполне безболезненно можно сделать. В середине или в конце предложения чаще замечаю, что союз расчленяют. Просто закономерность, которую можно не соблюдать, но я бы запятую не ставил.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы написал так:

1) "После того как боль чуть-чуть отходит, я разгибаюсь и смотрю на своего обидчика.",

2.1) "Я разгибаюсь и смотрю на своего обидчика, после того как боль чуть-чуть отходит.",

2.2) "Я разгибаюсь и смотрю на своего обидчика после того, как боль чуть-чуть отходит.".

**Причина**: В моём сознании русский трёхсловный союз "после того как" идентичен английскому однословному союзу "after", а русский трёхсловный союз "перед тем как" идентичен английскому однословному союзу "before".

Далее можно заметить следующее:

Предложение "После того как боль чуть-чуть отходит, я разгибаюсь и смотрю на своего обидчика." равносильно предложению "Перед тем как я разгибаюсь и смотрю на своего обидчика, боль чуть-чуть отходит.".

Предложение "Я разгибаюсь и смотрю на своего обидчика, после того как боль чуть-чуть отходит." равносильно предложению "Боль чуть-чуть отходит, перед тем как я разгибаюсь и смотрю на своего обидчика.".

Кроме того, можно заметить следующее:

Предложение "После того как боль чуть-чуть отходит, я разгибаюсь и смотрю на своего обидчика." равносильно предложению "Событие «*Боль чуть-чуть отходит*.» **предшествует** последовательности событий «*Я разгибаюсь и смотрю на своего обидчика*.».".

Предложение "Перед тем как я разгибаюсь и смотрю на своего обидчика, боль чуть-чуть отходит." равносильно предложению "Последовательность событий «*Я разгибаюсь и смотрю на своего обидчика*.» **следует за** событием «*Боль чуть-чуть отходит*.».".

Comment: Зачем вечно проводить аналогии с английским? Два разных языка, в каждом из них свои правила, свои союзы и прочее.

Comment: См. гипотезу Сепира-Уорфа.

Comment: "Нас и тут неплохо кормят". См. "Возвращение блудного попугая".

Я просто замечу, что ресурс рассчитан на пользователей, котрые в большинстве своём могут не владеть английским в должной мере, им бы с русским разобраться. 
А уж объяснять что-либо весьма сомнительной теорией - это, пардон, уже полный... гм... моветон.

Comment: Гипотеза Сепира-Уорфа, извините, полная лажа. Даже в Википедии написано, что эта гипотеза ни разу не поддерживается современными лингвистами, следовательно, она несостоятельна.

Comment: По моему мнению, Вы вправе отождествлять словосочетание "гипотеза Сепира-Уорфа" не только со словосочетанием "полная лажа", но и со словом "суперлабуда".

Comment: А по моему мнению Вы просто обязаны это сделать. Жаль только, что приходится говорить об этом именно здесь.